# Transforming a long date string to a Date in R

Tags: r

I have a date variable that is formatted as:

```
25-APR-2013 03.05.03.000000000 PM
```

I have converted it to a character and tried to get it to format. I did use the help documentation for as.Date but it did not help me.

I am trying to find a solution to get this into a Date type of the standard %Y-%m-%d

```
> df$DELETE_DATE
[1] "01-JUN-2011 05.24.12.000000000 AM" 
[2]"01-SEP-2011 03.54.01.000000000 AM" 
[3]"01-SEP-2012 05.20.10.000000000 AM"
[4] "01-JAN-2013 02.45.55.000000000 AM"
```

This is 4 out of 3.6 million.

I am open to any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Do you want a date or a date-time?

Comment: Just the date, the time is of no concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the date, then just specify that portion in the `format` argument:

```
as.Date("25-APR-2013 03.05.03.000000000 PM","%d-%b-%Y")
#[1] "2013-04-25"
```

If you wanted the full date-time, use `as.POSIXct` with a custom `format`:

```
as.POSIXct("25-APR-2013 03.05.03.000000000 PM",format="%d-%b-%Y %I.%M.%OS %p")
#[1] "2013-04-25 15:05:03 CDT"
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I wasnt sure how to handle the long time format. Both examples are perfect - thanks Josh.

Answer (score 2):

Just extract the portion of the string containing the useful info with `substr()` and feed it to `as.Date()`

```
orig.string<-"25-APR-2013 03.05.03.000000000 PM"
as.Date(substr(orig.string, start=1, stop=11), format="%d-%b-%Y")
```

Comment: This is a great example of how to use substr for this problem. Thanks for you suggestion.